# HTML DOM not working/returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I'm writing a JavaScript/HTML program and am using XML to contain most data. The XML DOM loader seems to always return  `undefined`. Here is the code I am using:

```
function loadXML(filename) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

And calling it with `loadXML("pages.xml");`

The function always returns `undefined` or `null`.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same piece of code as you do, even with the comment-lines ;). Where you return, i have `xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;`. Then after that, i can use $(xml).find('whateverimlookingfor') to navigate.

So either try adding my line and `console.log(xml)` to see if it returns something, or check if your URL is correct. As you put it, your XML is on the same level, in the same folder as your current file. If this is not true, your URL isn't correct.

EDIT: see you use xhttp rather than xml http:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','pages.xml',false);
xmlhttp.send();
xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: Works. I guess I might be using an old piece of code.